# Losing columns in Dask group by expression

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
                          EVENT_TYPE PRICE  TICKER
TIME            
2018-07-02 06:00:00.030691  TRADE   22.52   HPQ
```

My group by is as follows:

```
g = dfs[dfs.EVENT_TYPE == 'TRADE'].groupby(['TICKER', pd.Grouper(freq="D")])
g.first().compute()
```

However, the output only as the group by columns:

```
TICKER  TIME
AAPL    2018-07-02
        2018-07-03
        2018-07-05
        2018-07-06
```

I can't reproduce this with random data using Pandas or Dask.  In other similar questions, there was a recommendation to use reset_index, but when I called reset_index on the output, I received another exception ("The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata", even though I'm not providing metadata for the group by operation), and it isn't clear to me that the problems stems from whether I need to use the group by keys as the index or not, anyway.

Thanks a lot in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I recommend trying to create a minimal reproducible example.  It's difficult to help otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to do so this week and post when I have.

Comment: have the same problem. don't know what's wrong.